# how can i get actual file type from base64 String or file uri or bytearray in react native or js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs, react-native

i want to check actual file type from base64 string or byte array.

for example if i renamed extension of file from jpg to txt or something then it should give me original mime type of file. is there any idea how to do it for js or react .

i tried using buffer and blob but it only returns Bytearray. here is the code,

```
let file = "ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2U2NCxkR1Z6ZEFvPQ==";
     let buffer = Buffer.from(file,'base64').toJSON();
      console.log(file,buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the base64 to a Blob object, and the easiest way is to use the `fetch API` for that.

```js
const base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,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'

fetch(base64Image)
.then(
  async (res) => this.document.getElementById('image').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(await res.blob())
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="image" />
</body>
</html>
```